# How to get started writing iCal plugins?

Tags: macos, plugins, icalendar

I'd like to write an iCal plugin to help me cope with the need to put most events I create onto two calendars. Google is uncharacteristically less than helpful in providing programming resources for this purpose. Can someone here provide pointer(s)?

Comment: Let's see, do you own a time machine with which to tell what google had to say about this in 2010? Because, in fact, it had just about nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider using the `Apple Events` scripting interface built into `iCal` (and many other OS X apps), accessible via AppleScript or scripting bridges such as [appscript](http://appscript.sourceforge.net/).  Use the Open Dictionary menu item in `AppleScript Editor.app` (as it is now known in OS X 10.6) to view the complete `iCal` scripting dictionary.  There is a somewhat old but probably still useful introduction to iCal scripting [here](http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.21/21.11/ScriptingiCal/index.html).