# Mac: Plugin for iCal Mac

Tags: macos

I would like to add a plug-in for Mac's iCal. I would like to sync the calendar appointments between our server and Mac's iCal to and fro. I searched a lot but couldn't find anything. Is it possible to do it through a plugin. Is it feasible? Can i start program a plugin using Mac API's to access iCal calendar events? Please advise!

Thank you!

Comment: @downvoters please point out the reason of the down votes.

Comment: I didn't downvote the question, but there does appear to be a pretty similar thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274009/how-to-get-started-writing-ical-plugins?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

You don't really need to do a plugin per-se, but instead you can just write a background application that uses the [CalendarStore framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/CalendarStoreReference/_index.html), which allows you to access the same calendar data as iCal uses. If you want to be notified when an event changes, take a look at the notifications documented in the CalCalendarStore class (e.g. CalEventsChangedExternallyNotification). You can then take whatever action is needed to pass those changes on to your server.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot Brian. Could you give me some help on, 1.) How to write a background app. I just created an application normally. Any idea to create a background app. I also want to ask user to ask for login before doing sync in the background. 2. How to check if already event is pushed to iCal from my app? Lets say i logged-in and synced my server data into iCal. In the next sync, my app needs to check to not to same data being duplicated in iCal. How to check this? Please advise, thank you and appreciate your helps.

Answer (score 2):

If your server speaks CalDAV, you're in luck. iCal does.

Comment: CalDAV is supported in server, can i program a plug-in app on Mac, which can work with iCal? If possible, could you explain some more about..

Comment: Bascially.. beyond being able to get and set event data via CalDAV.. what exactly _would_ you want to do?

Comment: I want to develop a plug-in program(/app) for iCal, which can run always background in Mac and able to access iCal's data in Mac. Whenever any calendar events created/modified in iCal, this plugin can pull the created/modified calendar event data and send to server. And, whenever Calendar event created or modified on the server, this will be reflected to iCal as well through the plug-in. This Plug-in basically needs to sync the calendar events between iCal and our server. Please advise, how is this feasible?